# I have the CSS & JS, how do I convert that to erb for my Rails app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have the foundation of my Rails app, then I went ahead and did the JS and CSS.

How do I then take the CSS and JS that I have, and apply it to the app in a 'Rails Way'. i.e. a dynamic way that works nicely.

Can you give me some tutorials/articles/resources that I can read up to guide me, please?

I have tried the Rails guides, but I find them a bit lacking.

Any other good suggestions or tips that might help get me on the right track?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by a dynamic way? Do you mean separating JS and CSS into separate files that may be included in the relevant view?

Comment: Meaning...I want to include the js in one place, and it is automatically included on every page - I get that I would put this in application.html.erb file. But that's just one example. What else would I want to be done dynamically given that I have the JS & CSS already ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dynamic behavior in any web application can be expressed by using server side code, and/or client side code. In the client side there is a combination of techniques called AJAX that help to create a fluent interaction with the user.

You can learn a lot of Rails watching screencasts. You can have a look at [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/) or [PeepCode](http://peepcode.com) which are plenty of good tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know exactly what you're looking for, but one thing I'd start with is using [HAML](http://haml-lang.com/) instead of ERB.

HAML is about as "railsy" as you can get for writing views. It saves tons of typing, and is simply beautiful to look at. Check it out :)

Comment: It's best to learn the Rails way before starting to inject plugin dependencies, learn another template language and do too much too soon.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the `javascript_include_tag` and `stylesheet_tag`?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-javascript_include_tag